# Fetching issue with laravel excel Dropdown | can not open excel file in MS Excel

Tags: excel, laravel-excel, laravel-10

When i export excel file from live server. can't open file.
i'm using  "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1" package. and i'm trying to add dropdown in column.

```
protected $selects;
protected $row_count;
protected $column_count;

public function sheets(): array
{
    $sheets = [];
    $sheets[] = new AdvanceExportSampleQuestionBank();
    $sheets[] = new QuestionGroupSheet();
    $sheets[] = new AdvanceExportSampleQuestionBankGideline();
    return $sheets;
}

public function title(): string
{
    return 'Import';
}

public function __construct()
{
    $type = ['MultiChoice', 'ShortAnswer', 'LongAnswer', 'Matching'];
    $levels = QuestionLevel::where('status', 1)->pluck('title')->toArray();
    $yesNo = ['Yes', 'No'];
    $selects = [
        ['columns_name' => 'B', 'options' => $type],
        ['columns_name' => 'C', 'options' => [], 'sheet_name' => 'question_group', 'count' => QuestionGroup::count()],
        ['columns_name' => 'D', 'options' => $levels],
        ['columns_name' => 'E', 'options' => $yesNo],
    ];
    $this->selects = $selects;
    $this->row_count = 1000;//number of rows that will have the dropdown
    $this->column_count = 11;//number of columns to be auto sized
}

public function view(): View
{
    return view('advancequiz::exports.advance-sample-bulk-question');
}


public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
            $row_count = $this->row_count;
            $column_count = $this->column_count;
            foreach ($this->selects as $select) {
                $drop_column = $select['columns_name'];
                $cell = $drop_column . '2';
                $validation = $event->getSheet()->getDataValidation($cell);

                $validation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
                $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');

                if (isset($select['sheet_name'])) {
                    $validation->setFormula1("{$select['sheet_name']}!\$A\$1:\$A\${$select['count']}");
                } else {
                    $options = $select['options'];
                    $validation->setFormula1(sprintf('"%s"', implode(',', $options)));
                }
                $validation->setFormula2('');
                // Clone validation to remaining rows
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_column}{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation);
                }

                // Set columns to autosize
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $column_count; $i++) {
                    $column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
                    $event->sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            }
        },
    ];
}
```

Here is my code for export.
I'm using multisheet.

Note: this code works another project (in same server) all well. Also works in localhost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qctYF.png)

**Xls** formet is Ok in live but i'm trying to export **.xlsx** formet. but when export file as .xlsx formet its not working.
Try to use `ob_start()`;

`ob_start();`

`return Excel::download(new AdvanceExportSampleQuestionBank(), 'sample-questions.xls');`